# How to find a character in a string?

Tags: c++

I have already checked topics similar to this one but no one has been able to solve this problem.

So, I have to look for a character inside a string but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (tracciatonuovos.find('T'))
{
    nterminale++;
}
```

The counter does not increase. But if I try to find an empty space, it counts for me, and yet the string is full

[image: see image of output]

First value is string, second is length of string, and third is the value of counter "nterminale".

Comment: You might want to learn what the [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find#Return_value).

Comment: Ah so I'm using the function the wrong way, ops.....

Comment: `find()` return the index if found. Your code will fail for the case where the character is in position 0 and will even pass in case the character not found. Check with `std::string::npos`

Answer (score 1):

use the find function from the std::string class

```
std::string mystr = "Some String with T";
size_t apos = mystr.find("T");
```

Read more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

If you want to find the first occurrence use :

> find_first_of

And if you want to repeatedly find all occurrences of a specific character you will also need to specify a search start position and will need to write a loop say something like :

```
size_t pos = 0;
while((pos = mystr.find(whatever, pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
   pos +=1;   
  // and your other logic here
}
```

Comment: If I have more T in my string it is not a single one, why? how can I do?

Comment: @AndreaLeto, use `std::count()` in that case. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: @AndreaLeto use a loop if you want to find all occurrences. You will need to learn how to program the string functions using various language constructs. I suggest you learn the basics of the language first before venturing into the library. Take a look at my updated answer